# How to change the fontsize of a csquotes' quotation?

Tags: fontsize, csquotes

I'm quoting some text thanks to the `csquotes` package, like this:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\blockquote[somebody]{Bla bla bla.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

I'd like the font size of the quotation to be smaller.

How could I acheive such a result?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for posting a great [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). What exactly would you like to have in a smaller font size? `Bla bla bla.`, `« Bla bla bla. »`, or `« Bla bla bla. » (somebody)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One idea of the `csquotes` package is to dynamically decide whether a quote is so long that it is typed as a blockquote, or whether it is short enough to be typed inline. I assume that you don't want to change the font size of inline quotes, but rather of block quotes.

To do that, you need to know that the `\blockquote` just calls the `quote` environment, so we just need to change the formatting settings for this environment. This example shows how to do that using the packages `etoolbox` and `relsize`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller}

\begin{document}
Bla bla bla.

\blockquote[somebody]{Bla bla bla.\\}

Bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note that I added the linebreak `\\` only to trigger that `csquotes` typesets the quote as a blockquote.)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following renewed environment with `csquotes`. Copy it to your preamble.

```
\renewenvironment{quote}{\list{}{\rightmargin0pt\leftmargin0pt}\item\relax
\small\singlespacing}{\endlist}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quote}
```

`\rightmargin0pt\leftmargin0pt` declares the margins of the quotation (0pt each indicates that is textwidth). What you are looking for is the command `\small` which sets the quotation one step smaller than the normal text.

Answer (score 1):

`\blockquote` is actually a dynamic command that switches between typesetting its argument inline (if it is shorter than a threshold set with the package options `threshold` and `thresholdtype`) or in display mode (i.e. as a real block quotation separated by line/paragraph breaks). These two modes can be modified independently.

If you always want to typeset block quotes regardless of the length, maybe `\begin{displayquote}...\end{displayquote}` is more to the point. The behaviour of that environment can be controlled with `\SetBlockEnvironment` amongst others.

---

Specifically for the job of making block quotes smaller [`csquotes.cfg` suggest to define a new environment based on `quote` that can then be used for `\blockquote` with `\SetBlockEnvironment`](https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/ad510ad33fea8dab7cd530e1d533b0724847396d/csquotes.cfg#L221-L227).

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{relsize}

\newenvironment*{smallquote}
  {\quote\smaller}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\blockquote[somebody]{Lorem ipsum. A short inline quote.}
\lipsum[2]
\blockquote[somebody]{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: inline quote unchanged in quotation marks, longer block code smaller]

---

Alternatively, you can use the hooks provided by `csquotes`.

The inline quotation can be modified by redefining the hook `\mktextquote`, the block quotation by changing `\mkblockquote`.

It would look odd to have inline quotations in a different font size, so I'm assuming you only want to change the block quotation. The default definition for `\mkblockquote` is

```
\newcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{#1#2#4#3}
```

we just add a `\smaller` (from `\usepackage{relsize}` as suggested in [Tiuri](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/103046/tiuri)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370024/35864)) and then use `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{relsize}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\smaller#1#2#4#3}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\blockquote[somebody]{Lorem ipsum. A short inline quote.}
\lipsum[2]
\blockquote[somebody]{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The output in this example is as shown above.

---

`\SetBlockEnvironment` also affects `\begin{displayquote}...\end{displayquote}`, but for finer control those environments can be customised with `\mkbegdispquote` and `\mkenddispquote`, whose defaults are

```
\newcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{}
\newcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{#1#2}
```

So we could also use

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{relsize}
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\smaller}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{displayquote}[somebody]
Lorem ipsum. A short inline quote.
\end{displayquote}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{displayquote}[somebody]
\lipsum[3]
\end{displayquote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 from me. And I also did try TL2018 and Overleaf, and `\AtBeginEnvironment` did not work for this with either indeed. But the accepted answer suggests my memory on this might not be completely misguided (though I do admit I might have been doing something else, like redefining the environment, or defining another one).