# setspace and quote: why is the pre-quote content spacing messed up?

Tags: line-spacing, quoting, csquotes, setspace

I'm trying to set my main document to one-and-a-half spacing, and have single spacing for indented quotations.

I noticed a good way of doing it was suggested in [How to style blockquote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325695/how-to-style-blockquote), however when I try to apply that for an indented quote within a paragraph, the single spacing is applied to the preceding text:

[image: screenshot]

What is the mechanism applying the spurious single space before and how to correct that?

A workaround is to do a line break between the first `\lipsum[66]` and `\begin{quote}`, but that is semantically 'incorrect' since they are supposed to belong to the same paragraph.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\onehalfspacing

\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[75]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some settings in TeX and LaTeX apply to the complete paragraph, the line spacing set with `\onehalfspacing` and `\singlespacing` is one such setting. Usually the paragraph is typeset with the settings active at the end of the paragraph.

Internally `quote` is implemented as a `\list`, which at some point calls `\par` to start a new paragraph for the list.

With the patch the code in the question then essentially ends up executing

```
\lipsum[66]
{\singlespace\list...\endlist}
```

where `\list` includes a `\par` call. That means LaTeX sees something similar to the following situation

```
\lipsum[66]{\singlespace\par}
```

Here the paragraph is ended and the entire paragraph is typeset with the line spacing setting active *at that point*. So the entire paragraph is typeset with single spacing.

Clearly this is not what we want. One solution would be to manually end the paragraph before you go into `quote` (this is what you found in the question already). If this feels semantically wrong, you could force the `\par` (which `quote` will execute anyway) a little bit earlier by including it in the patch

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\onehalfspacing

\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[75]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image: Single-spaced quote and one-half-spaced surrounding text.]

Since you are loading `csquotes` I recommend you actually use one of its environments instead of the standard `quote`. We can then modify its behaviour as suggested in `csquotes.cfg` and shown in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602258/35864) to [How to change the fontsize of a csquotes' quotation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370022/35864)

For the semantically nicer solution we have to use the internal implementation of `\singlespacing` as setting `\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}` to avoid the space correction introduced by `\singlespacing`.

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}

\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{singlequote}
  {\quote\setstretch{\setspace@singlespace}}
  {\endquote}
\makeatother

\SetBlockEnvironment{singlequote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{displayquote}
  \lipsum[75]
\end{displayquote}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying your code without any changes to the spacing the quote in the output has a blank line before and after it. It thus looks intermediate between the two `\lipsum[66]`.

If you want the output to show no extra space before the quoute then put some negative space before it. For instance:

```
% spacingpob.tex SE 569716
\documentclass[UKenglish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\onehalfspacing

%\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespacing}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\onehalfspacing\singlespacing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}
\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[75]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

I think that you might need to distinguish between thinking about the *semantics* in the LaTeX versus that in the output.

Comment: I'm not interested in the vertical space between the preceding paragaph and the quote, but the line spacing affecting the preceding paragraph. Unless there's something I'm missing.