# Change font of csquotes' block quotation

Tags: quoting, csquotes

I'm trying to change the fontsize of `csquotes`' blockquotes, but seem to be facing some unexpected hard-time.

I know `csquotes` uses an environment for that, which is by default `quote`, and can be set with `\SetBlockEnvironment`. And I do recall being able to use a "begin environment" hook on that single environment for this purpose. And I think I'm not going senile on this (yet), since I am able to find advice along these lines here on the site (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370024/105447 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370027/105447).

However, this is currently not working (so, please consider this before flagging duplicate). A MWE to demonstrate:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\footnotesize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quotation}

\begin{displayquote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My question here is then is: is this expected behavior? Has something changed in this regard with the new hook system?

If it is not expected, where should I report it: `csquotes` or `latex`?

If it is expected, what is the current best method to change font size for `csquotes`' block quotes? (including `\blockquote` and friends).

Comment: `displayquote` essentially calls, with your setting, `\quotation`, not `\begin{quotation}`, so the hooks pertaining to the `quotation` environment are not applied. As far as I can see, your idea would have never worked.

Comment: Can you explain which output you want to see? I'm guessing you want `quotation` also to show in small and bold? I just checked with older versions of TeX Live on Overleaf and the output is always the same as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, moewe, that's what I'd expect to see. But, as you and @egred observed, the hypothesis I'm not senile on that memory yet, may well be wrong.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into using official `csquotes` hooks for these kinds of things.

There is `\mkblockquote` for `\blockquote` and friends as well as `\mkbegdispquote`/`\mkenddispquote` for `displayquote` and friends.

So to make `displayquote` go small and bold, you could use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\footnotesize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

[image: Small and bold displayquote.]

---

For smaller display quotes [`csquotes.cfg` suggest something along the lines of](https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/ad510ad33fea8dab7cd530e1d533b0724847396d/csquotes.cfg#L221-L227)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\newenvironment*{footnoteboldquote}
  {\quote\footnotesize\bfseries}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{footnoteboldquote}

\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, moewe! I think `\mkbegdispquote` is the appropriate way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, moewe, that's a good one too.

Answer (score 1):

This has never worked, even if the `etoolbox` hook mechanism is used (so with LaTeX kernels prior to the 2020-10-01 release).

The problem is that `\begin{displayquote}` does `\csuse{\csq@blockenvironment}` (and similarly for `\end{displayquote}`), which in your case reduces to executing `\quotation`. Thus the hooks pertaining to the environment are not executed: they're triggered by `\begin{quotation}`.

You can solve the issue by patching the relevant commands to use `\begin{\csq@blockenvironment}` and `\end{\csq@blockenvironment}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quotation}{\footnotesize\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\csq@bdquote}{\csuse}{\begin}{}{}
\patchcmd{\csq@edquote}{\csuse{end\csq@blockenvironment}}{\end{\csq@blockenvironment}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quotation}

\begin{displayquote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I fervently hope that `\bfseries` is used only by way of example.

Comment: Probably my memory has failed me this time. About "I fervently hope that `\bfseries` is used only by way of example." Yes, of course!, and `\footnotesize` too. :-)  Thank you very much! But, even though your answer gets the job (well) done, I think moewe's got a point with `\mkbegdispquote` as a more "user level" handle for the purpose.